# net:: ERR CONNECTION REFUSED Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm making an small Person Management System (like an agenda) with Angular. Its my first Angular Application.

I've been following this tutorial:
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-11-crud-rest-api-tutorial/

And had problems before that were solved on this post:
[Object is possibly null - Angular (ts2531) [Can't get it fixed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759476/object-is-possibly-null-angular-ts2531-cant-get-it-fixed)

However, after getting my application to run, when i try to create a person i just receive a "Connection Refused" message. Based on what i searched, the message is about my API not being active therefore it can't make the connection for running the operations. How could i test and fix it?

Any input is very much appreciated. Thanks.

The error:
person-list.component.ts:59          GET http://localhost:8080/api/persons?name=Pablo net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(Whenever i try to access the api persons)

## **person-create-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonService } from 'src/app/services/person.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person-create',
  templateUrl: './person-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person-create.component.css']
})
export class PersonCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  person = {
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    address: '',
    phone: '',
    whatsapp: '',
    instagram: '',
    available: false
  };
  submitted = false;

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createPerson(): void {
    const data = {
      name: this.person.name,
      surname: this.person.surname,
      address: this.person.address,
      phone: this.person.phone,
      whatsapp: this.person.whatsapp,
      instagram: this.person.instagram,
      available: this.person.available
    };

    this.personService.create(data)
      .subscribe( //According to chrome console, the error is on this line.
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  newPerson(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.person = {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      address: '',
      phone: '',
      whatsapp: '',
      instagram: '',
      available: false
    };
  }

}
```

## **person-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/persons';

export type Person =
{  
  available: boolean;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  address: string;
  phone: string;
  whatsapp: string;
  instagram: string;
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PersonService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  
  readAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(baseURL);
  }

  read(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${baseURL}/${id}`);
  }

  create(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(baseURL, data);
    
  }
  update(id: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.put(`${baseURL}/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${baseURL}/${id}`);
  }

  deleteAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.delete(baseURL);

    
  }

  searchByName(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${baseURL}?name=${name}`);
  }


}
```

Comment: Are you having CORS problems ?

Comment: No, there are no mentions about CORS errors in the console.

Comment: what backend are you using for your application?

Comment: I'm developing the application using Node.js + Angular. I'm totally new to Angular, started yesterday :) ! Following an tutorial, changed the names, got it working (with some help from other post) and now that its running i'm having this error.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` sounds like there is no backend running or it's not running on port `8080` And looking at the linked tutorial: They don't implement the backend (may be it's explained in another tutorial)

Comment: I tought it was a functional tutorial =(! On my person-service.ts i changed the baseURL port but all it did was to stop showing error messages (i click on create and nothing happens). Let me startover with another tutorial, thanks for the info :)